# can't figure out unrecognized selector sent to instance for XMLparser

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I had a function XMLParser working but I'm trying to expand the class to handle different XML files my app needs.

I'm getting the error "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[XMLParser initXMLParserForValidation]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7564ea0'" Here's the code there.

```
- (void)validateEmail:(NSString *)urlString {
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSXMLParser *nsXmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
XMLParser *parser = [[XMLParser alloc] initXMLParserForValidation];
[nsXmlParser setDelegate:parser];

BOOL wasSuccessful = [nsXmlParser parse];

if (wasSuccessful) {
    self.result = [parser result];
} 
}
```

I've put breakpoints and stuff and but doesn't even get into my initXMLParserForValidation class. Here it is anyway, though.

```
- (XMLParser *) initXMLParserForValidatation {
self = [super init];
_result = [[ValidationResult alloc] init];
return self;
}
```

I've tried to mimic the code that's working but I can't see any differences. Driving me nuts. I'm new at this iphone stuff, though. Help much appreciated.

Comment: Be careful with that init method - you should always test the result of `[super init]` in case it failed, ie: `if (!(self = [super init])) { return nil; }`

Comment: *nod* Okay. Thanks. I'll try and maintain such practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a spelling error in the declaration of your class' init method:

initXMLParserForValida**ta**tion

Then you're calling the init method like this, with the proper spelling, which doesn't exist:

initXMLParserForValidation

Remove the extra `ta` and you should be good to go!

Comment: Thank you. You spotted that quick.